# Case when for subset and the whole set

Tags: sql, hive, case, impala

Im trying to count transactions and label them with case when statement in Hive.

```
select case    
  When PROTOCOLID = 61002 AND TRANS_TYPE = "succesfull"  THEN "X"   
When PROTOCOLID = 61002 AND (TRANS_TYPE ="succesfull" or TRANS_TYPE ="failed") THEN "Y"
   end as name, sum(count)
 from tab1
 group by name
```

But so far it seems that only the broader (succesfull + failed) when statement returns the results while the one for succesfull transactions is not returned.

EDIT: the more I work with the query, it seems it always return the when condition I put at first place. So lets say I have **10 transaction in total** and put the the case when condition for SUCCESS transaction first, I get the result as folows:
7 transaction succesfull
3 transaction total (succesfuul + failed)

It looks like the group by is what is causing troubles

Comment: @scaisEdge I can see I have both types of transactions there, if I sum the counts individualy for succesfull and all types of transactions, I get the results

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  I would get this information using:

```
select count(*) as cnt_total,
       sum(case when trans_type = 'successful' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_success    
from tab1
where trans_type in ('succesful', 'failed') and
      protocolid = 61002;
```

My suspicion is that you simply misspelled "succesful", though.

Comment: The whole query will create a view for pulling the data from aggregate table with more than the protocolid=61002, that is why I was trying to use the case when. Checked the spelling and its allright, sorry for my english though, my bad!

Comment: Assuming you have multiple protocol_id values and only successful/failed for trans_type, just add protocol_id to your select, and group by that.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for the tip, unfortunately I have successfull/failed/unknown

Comment: @k_mishap . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask.  However, if you want multiple protocol ids, then this is easily modified to use `group by` and summarize for each one.